# Bootstrap CSS row fill parent column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am trying to make is so that I can fill a parent `div.col` with second child `div.row`, but it seems I cannot make it work using bootstrap `flex-box`. 
What I've tried so far is this:

```
<div class="column col-12 d-flex" >
   <div class="row">
        <div class="column-name col">{this.props.name}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row align-self-stretch">
        <Lane /> /*React class*/
   </div>
</div>
```

Parent `div.column` fills it's parent properly, but what I am trying to do is make second `div.row` fill the remaining space left from first `div.row`.
This code only breaks the layout of the page, and it is not a solution for me, because it also stretched first `div.row`.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you're trying to do here, because it sounds to me like you want the two `.row` classes that are children of `.column` to behave like `.col` instead of like `.row` ?

Comment: Yes, but `.row` stays collapsed if it does not have any children, but I want it to stretch even without content.

Comment: Do you mean you want equal-height columns like this: https://www.bootply.com/vWVWEpIURq ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our brief conversation it sounds like you're trying to manipulate Bootstrap's Grid in an odd behavior when you could rely on its default behavior.  Instead of trying to treat each `.row` like it should behave as a column; just use columns.

There are several other ways to achieve equal-height columns in Bootstrap 4 but here is one that I *personally* find quick and easy:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="h-100 p-3 bg-dark text-light">
        <p>This only has a little bit of text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="h-100 p-3 bg-info text-light">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside of each column is an `h-100` wrapper which forces the contents to take up 100% of the available space.  This will force each column to have a height equal to the tallest column.